# Downloading in parallel using wget or aria2 in windows from FTP site

Tags: ftp, wget, aria2

How can I download all files (in parallel) using wget2 or aria from here: ftp://ftp.soilgrids.org/data/recent/

I tried `aria2c -j 8 ftp://ftp.soilgrids.org/data/recent/` but it does not do anything (and does not show any error message either)

I am on windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wget` is not multi-threaded, so you would need to somehow split the URLs in packages and invoke the program multiple times. On the other hand, `aria2` [is not able to recursively download](https://github.com/aria2/aria2/issues/421). Since you're on Windows, I can't assume much useful besides `cmd` and the given `wget` and `aria2`.

We can download the directory listing with `wget` and construct a text file with the URLs for `aria2` to download in parallel. A little batch file will massage the data correspondingly:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion    
SET host=ftp://ftp.soilgrids.org/data/recent
DEL urls.txt

REM fetch dirlisting from ftp
wget --no-remove-listing !host!/

FOR /F "tokens=1,9" %%G IN (.listing) DO (
    SET "modeflags=%%G"
    REM skip directories
    IF "x!modeflags:d=!"=="x!modeflags!" (
        ECHO !host!/%%H >> urls.txt
    )
)

REM cleanup
DEL .listing.*
DEL index.html.*
```

Then, you can just do...

```
aria2c -j8 -i urls.txt
```

...to download the files in parallel.